# Submitting Hidden Form Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net

We have recently switched from ASP to PHP and we used to have a form that included a automatic field to login users using a file called `<!--#include file="XXX.inc" -->`.

Is there a way to do the same thing using php?  If not can I use JavaScript or JQuery?

It is only two fields:
UserName
UserPassword

The code we were using is:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com" target="_self">
 <!--#include file="bslogin.inc" -->
<input type="image" name="btn_login" src="../images/GoDatabase_off.jpg" alt="Go to the  Database" width="125" height="38" border="0">
```

Both of which were supplied by the .inc file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, it is just the same, but you'll include the file using:

```
include('bslogin.inc');
```

Your HTML has

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="xxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="xxx" />
```

PHP sees it in the `$_POST` as `$_POST['username']`

Comment: Sorry..follow up question.  I'm using Joomla, so I need to put the .inc file in a subdirectory so it can be found.  How do I do that?  If i just give it a / it won't work.  Thanks again!

Comment: Sure; you'll likely want to put it somewhere where you can find the location of it, so you can put it in a folder at the same level as Joomla's index file. I would then, personally attempt to look for it from the calling file: so `include('../../bslogin.inc)` if the file was two up from the calling location. Also check that your server is configured to read .inc files.

Comment: Thanks Shamil.  I've tried that, but for some reason Joomla isn't letting my find the inc file.  I've done a test php file and put it in the root with the inc and it works fine.  But when I menu to the page it goes haywire.  Not sure how to direct path it to where the file should be.

Comment: Your host would be the best bet to find the direct path of the file

Comment: Thanks again Shamil, I wish I could give you another check or +1.  I ended up using a wrapper and pointing to the file on the root directory.  It is kind of cheating, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP does have a way to include files. Here's [a tutorial with example syntax](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php).